# Do you need to re-install a Windows service after rebuilding

Tags: c#, windows-services

If I rebuild a Windows Service after making changes, can I just copy and replace the old assembly / .exe files to get those changes to run or do I need to re-install the service? Also do I have to first uninstall the service before installing the new version?

Comment: No, it's not needed to re-install. Just copy the files. And if you install the files from the Bin directory of the Visual Studio, just a build will update the service already.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You don't have to uninstall and reinstall the service since this only adds registry info regarding the executable path and launch options. Just stop the service, copy your assemblies and restart it

Comment: When you installed the service, you installed it from a directory. This is the root of your directory structure so you should copy your assemblies there. To find out what directory your service was installed from take a look at its properties: `sc qc SERVICE_NAME` and look for the BINARY_PATH_NAME property

Answer (score -1):

You do not need to uninstall the service just make changes in your files after stopping the service and then start again it will consider your changes..

I would suggest you to use [Topshelf](http://topshelf-project.com/) for service hosting.

Comment: What is the advantage of Topshelf? Also I have no config files, I was more talking about rebuilding so that there are changes to the actual application/assembly

Comment: I meant for the files you need to replace not just config file sorry for that @Dan and for topshelf I said because I am using it in many of my services http://www.christophdebaene.com/blog/2011/03/16/create-a-net-windows-service-in-5-steps-with-topshelf/ and http://www.codeguru.com/columns/dotnet/services-made-easy.htm