# Custom Windows Service Keeps failing

Tags: c#, .net, windows, service

I have had to make changes to an assembly reference for a project that runs as a service.

Since then I have had trouble getting the thing to run. It seems that somewhere along the execution of this thing it fails and stops the service.

The .dll in question has been deployed to other projects that run as a scheduled task and hasn't caused any issues there.

This post here ([stackoverflow services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26253357/do-you-need-to-re-install-a-windows-service-after-rebuilding?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)) suggests that all I need to do is stop the service and start it up again having swapped out the dlls, but I get the feeling I am missing something?

Or even better is there a way to see if the executable that the service runs is working, like in task manager?

EDIT:

I can see what is breaking it and it's entityframe work throwing an exception relating to MetaData, I have a "Core" and and "Application" layer to this project, the core handles the data and the EF models, but it seems the metadata between the connection strings is different eg:

```
metadata=res://*/EntityFramework.AutomaticOrderingEntities.csdl|res://*/EntityFramework.AutomaticOrderingEntities.ssdl|res://*/EntityFramework.AutomaticOrderingEntities.msl;
```

which is different to the below:

```
metadata=res://*/EntityFramework.WebstoreEntities.csdl|res://*/EntityFramework.WebstoreEntities.ssdl|res://*/EntityFramework.WebstoreEntities.msl;
```

They are both the same name and catalog etc in the connection strings, do they have to be the same?

Comment: It's very difficult to know what the problem is if we have absolutely no idea what your code does.

Comment: Are there no errors logged anywhere?  Or do you just get "The service failed to start"?  Perhaps provide information of the DLL being a signed or not or has a specified assembly version number etc.  Typically you will see your exe running in task manager - have you actually checked?

Comment: Do you mean you changed the DLL and did not recompile the Exe and just swapped the DLL? That is not what the linked post is about. You should swap *all* files, not just some.

Comment: Also if its a .net DLL you can use fusion logviewer to see if it is loading you dependencies correctly - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/fuslogvw-exe-assembly-binding-log-viewer.

Comment: Hi All, thanks for the responses so far I have recompiled the project (clean, rebuild) and took all the files out of the bin folder and stuck them where the project "lives".  I will checkout fusion logviewer. I can see that the application actually writes to the event log so I will check that (sorry If I have wasted time here)